# Set default Apache caching behavior, overide with .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http

How do I set Apache set HTTP headers which cache all resources for 15 mins but also allow .htaccess files in a directory to override these settings on a per-site basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) (telling browsers how to cache the content), then you would put something like this in your httpd.conf:

```
ExpiresDefault A900 #15 minutes
```

And then in the .htaccess:

```
ExpiresDefault A3600 #1 hour
```

You can also override by type of resource, using `ExpiresByType`

If you're talking about caching the content server-side ([mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html)), these directives can only be done in httpd.conf and vhosts files. .htaccess cannot override them.

Comment: Yes mod_expires is what I'm talking about,so ExpiresDefault will work for any type of resource?

Comment: assuming in your main httpd.conf configuration you haven't set a ExpiresByType, then ExpiresDefault should be what you want for all resources. If you did specify a type (resource), you'll have to override it also in the .htaccess